# Compare regex in programming languages with regular expression from automata/formal language?

Tags: reference-request, programming-languages, regular-expressions

I'm trying to reconcile the differences/similarities between regular expression from formal language theory and automata, and the "regex" offered by programming languages.

These two differ not just in "syntax" (the union `+` in regular expressions means `|` in regex, and there's no such meta-character as `.` in regular expressions, etc.), but also in "semantics", e.g. the regular expression `(a+b)*c` describes the regular language, L=`{a,b}*{c}`, which the string `abcd` is not a member of, but the equivalent regex `(a|b)*c` would actually find a "match" in the string `abcd` (unless I do `(a|b)*c$`). Not to mention that "regex" can describe some non-regular languages as well.

Is there a good resource/summary that compares regular expression with "regex"?

Comment: Check out this one: https://nikic.github.io/2012/06/15/The-true-power-of-regular-expressions.html.

Comment: Anton's link provides some evidence that any regularity in what programmers call "regular expressions" is purely coincidental.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In programming, "regular expressions" are used for *searching* (if a match happens in the string), not for simple *accepting*. I.e., it is as if what is written is `.*your-re-here.*`.

It is often of interest to know not only if it matched, but exactly where. And so the above isn't all the story, most RE machines also look for the *longest* match. For simplicity, many RE libraries don't handle alternation (e.g. `ed(1)` in Unix of yore didn't), as characters, character classes, star applied to the last character, and anchors (beginning/end of line) were enough to handle 90% or more of the "text editing" requirements. And that can be written in [simple, short code](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr09/cos333/beautiful.html).

Furthermore, depending on the exact machinery used, it is more or less easy to extend the "regular expressions" with non-regular constructs, like "match what matched between parenteses before", like `([a-z]*) \1` to mean "the same word twice, separated by a space". Such constructs are handled e.g. in `vi(1)`, as tasks like the mentioned are useful to catch typos (a common error is to to write the same word twice).

Answer (score 1):

[Regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Standards) in programming languages provide many short cuts. Standard regular expressions only have only the following operators: $E+F,EF, E^*$ and $(E)$.

For example, say, POSIX regeular expression $[a-z]$. If we write this in standard way it will be $a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i+j+k+l+m+n+o+p+q+r+s+t+u+v+w+x+y+z$. So $[a-z]$ is just a shortcut. And, say POSIX regular expression $[$^$abc]$ which is anything but $a$ or $b$ or $c$.

Apart from these shortcuts,  there is no other difference. There is just a difference in syntax, but no semantic difference really.